# Trouble centre-aligning items within a QtQuick StackLayout

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

I'm having trouble centre-aligning items within a QtQuick StackLayout using qml. As far as I can see I'm doing things correctly according to the docs, but I can't get the behaviour I'm after. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I'd like to use a stack layout such that when the item at the current index is smaller than the minimum size of the layout, it is not stretched but positioned in the centre of the layout. I understand the mechanism for this is the `Layout.alignment` attached property which I set to `Qt.AlignHCenter | Qt.AlignVCenter` on the item, however this seems to have no effect. The item remains in the top left corner.

I also need the stack layout to have an implicit size of the Item at the current index, rather than the maximum size of all the items. This I think I have achieved by overriding the implicit size properties.

I've got a minimal reproduction of my issue in the snippet bellow. The red Rectangle should be centred within the `StackLayout`, however it is positioned in the top left corner. You can paste this into qmlonline.kde.org to get a quick render of the scene.

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.15
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15

ColumnLayout {
    StackLayout {
        id: stack
        
        currentIndex: 0
        implicitWidth: children[currentIndex].implicitWidth
        implicitHeight: children[currentIndex].implicitHeight
        
        Layout.minimumWidth: 400
        Layout.minimumHeight: 250
        Layout.fillWidth: true
        Layout.fillHeight: true
        
        Rectangle {
            color: "red"
            implicitWidth: 100
            implicitHeight: 100
            Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignHCenter | Qt.AlignVCenter
            Layout.fillHeight: false
            Layout.fillWidth: false
        }
                    
        Rectangle {
            color: "green"
            implicitWidth: 500
            implicitHeight: 300
            Layout.fillHeight: false
            Layout.fillWidth: false
        }
    }
    RowLayout {
        Button {
            text: "Red"
            onClicked: stack.currentIndex = 0
        }
        Button {
            text: "Green"
            onClicked: stack.currentIndex = 1
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If I'm correct, according to the QQuickStackLayout [source code](https://codebrowser.dev/qt5/qtdeclarative/src/imports/layouts/qquickstacklayout.cpp.html#252), the StackLayout doesn't have any alignment options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> understand the mechanism for this is the Layout.alignment attached property which I set to Qt.AlignHCenter | Qt.AlignVCenter on the item, however this seems to have no effect. The item remains in the top left corner.

StackLayout does not support `Layout.alignment` attached property... The list of supported properties is explicitly listed in [the documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtquick-layouts-stacklayout.html).

Simply wrap your rectangle inside an `Item`, which will occupy all space inside `StackLayout` by default and center `Rectangle` in it.

```
        Item {
            Rectangle {
                anchors.centerIn: parent
            
                color: "red"
                implicitWidth: 100
                implicitHeight: 100
            }
        }
```

> I also need the stack layout to have an implicit size of the Item at the current index, rather than the maximum size of all the items. This I think I have achieved by overriding the implicit size properties.

Yes, so simply bind wrapping `Item` implicit sizes to match wrapped `Rectangle`

```
        Item {
            implicitWidth: rect.implicitWidth
            implicitHeight: rect.implicitHeight
        
            Rectangle {
                id: rect
            
                anchors.centerIn: parent
            
                color: "red"
                implicitWidth: 100
                implicitHeight: 100
            }
        }
```

[Demo](https://qmlonline.kde.org/?code=JYWwDg9gTgLgBARRggrsAxgazgJgHQCMArAFCiSyLJpZ4AyAhgJ4QowDOcBhp508SVBkx4AwhAB2MKBAA2nfMRIlxslCAmMWbOAG8ScQ3ADKMBli2t4+o7bjAAJgC447M1gN3Dnr+hRQoAFMpAEkJB0CADxcABh87clkMYBgAdUcYAAsXdEzgWQcgiQBtPwDgmDCIyIBdPETktIzM+NsG9BSACUDgAHNMmBy8gqLS-yLK8Ki69q6e-phWoyXDSzY8EGAJUHV0hyyXABYYuK9V5isNrZ2Qbr6BlxwiU7O1mDwAM3zZPYO4aRQgRWcDen2+dwWLgBQLOcGBkhC4CSHSa+0yokyDAkvUCzjg6Ek7DkgTwsggvQAFLNUVkAJTAhmwkIwQIgPTAtpIxq-bJwILod7UnkcozUiEPPmBAX1Lko8WLWEiwwAJSlZmxskC7NhsMcLn5Cp13iNXixuWg7Dw6AqgSgYRcYAYEyVcJNdgJZKgLgAREEHN6XZywMiUjyXAQToHRbK5vdBlxI26AL7AlNuxWw1UCrG9TXak0e6A+3pBYIBt1C5ouZ4vI1i+YSgDMiZNoK+slk8pcHwY8hhrYu63bPyrcB7fdT8TTRmVEAA7m9814AEJsGCSJc6lmRePe1X+l2SUTIzC4lxucwiMoTKpROAAXjgtbs05Xa43NhN293AHFSxJyxNI8TzPVx3CvcYKlvSIHy4SdbBTJMgA)

Comment: Thanks for the response. I understand now - the alignment property is not supported. 

Unfortunately, your suggested solution will not work for my use case because the component I'm using (the Rectangle for the sake of the example) needs to sometimes be constrained by the bounding box of the Item. For example, if the Layout descides to squash the item to smaller than its implicitHeight, I need the Rectangle to be similarly squashed. In the suggestion this will not be the case.

Comment: It's a real shame that alignment is not supported. I can't see any neat way around this problem, other than using a `RowLayout` and manually setting the visible properties of the children to fake the behaviour of a stack. This is what I've had to go for in the end, btw.

Comment: @CrouchEndTiger you can bind `width` and `height` of the `Rectangle` to the `width` and `height` of the `Item`, then `Item` will become completely opaque. You didn't ask it in the original question, so I didn't put it into the code, but obviously you can do it.

Comment: But if I do that then I lose the effective center alignment on the Rectangle - it will simply fill the width and height, which I could have done without the item..

Comment: My desired layout is such that the Rectangle remains centred when either it’s width or height is less than the layout but is squashed when either dimension exceeds the size of the Layout.

Comment: @CrouchEndTiger thus bind `Rectangle` `width` to something like `Math.min(implicitWidth, parent.width)`

Comment: Sure, but then I’m just reimplementing the missing alignment property. Seems like a hole in the QtQuick.Layouts module which is supposed to handle exactly this stuff without expensive custom width bindings or wrapper Items.

Comment: @CrouchEndTiger I agree that Qt Quick layouts need some love from TQTC in general...

Answer (score -1):

[REWRITE]

`StackLayout` is typically useful when your children changes and that you wish your children to implicit inherit the dimensions of your parent, e.g.

```
Page {
    StackLayout {
        id: stack
        anchors.fill: parent
        Page { Rectangle { anchors.centerIn: parent; width: 100; height: 100; color: "red" } }
        Page { Rectangle { anchors.centerIn: parent; width: 500; height: 300; color: "green" } }
    }
    footer: RowLayout {
        Button { text: "Red"; onClicked: stack.currentIndex = 0; }
        Button { text: "Green"; onClicked: stack.currentIndex = 1; }
    }
}
```

However, in your case, the size of your children are independent and you want your children to have `Layout` properties such as `Layout.alignment`. In this case, I think we can refactor and remove `StackLayout` and directly control `visible` on the children:

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.15
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15
Page {
    property int currentIndex: 0
    ColumnLayout {
        width: parent.width
        Rectangle {
            color: "red"
            Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignHCenter | Qt.AlignVCenter
            Layout.preferredWidth: 100
            Layout.preferredHeight: 100
            visible: currentIndex === 0
        }
        Rectangle {
            color: "green"
            Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignHCenter | Qt.AlignVCenter
            Layout.preferredWidth: 500
            Layout.preferredHeight: 300
            visible: currentIndex === 1
        }
        RowLayout {
            Button {
                text: "Red"
                onClicked: currentIndex = 0
            }
            Button {
                text: "Green"
                onClicked: currentIndex = 1
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can [Try it Online!](https://stephenquan.github.io/qmlonline/?zcode=AAADf3icvVJNT8MwDL33V1j9AVUL2qVSD9ADQ+Kw7QDn0pouIk0q192HoP+dZEGDfjCVy94ptp/9/JKIqtbEsOZ1K/J3uAmihSd6ueApO+qWG4gmaqlWTFo2rnGVlQgfHhjUpGskPoJQDHlLhIofVYGHGMITIdWyrZSb/d1jsRcFb2OoM9sQnKJzbYM5Z6qU+ItvkWupKQafsPB7BTc9yKQoVWXmxWbv4M5Gy9SESPB5zjy7zFR/TfiGxkHx4paLwvAibYmi3PKYtxONeJUY9+4DkiSBH143221JiOoqfhcz/d7O9htN+dX70W+wuG+ZtRokLRgPRtTfDF/dQqtUmv+JxVAc+it2/5J6GF/5ZbHoDzF36rzuCyhB8i4=)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this doesn't really solve my problem. With these Page elements being resized by the StackLayout rather than the actual rectangles I lose much of the flexibility that I would gain from using a layout. For example if I further constrain my stack to have a maximum size then the rectangles will not be constrained within this maximum, they will overlap the parent pages which are constrained.

Comment: @CrouchEndTiger I rewrote my answer guessing your requirements. In your question I am still not entirely sure of the purpose of changing the dimensions of the StackLayout, but, as in the above rewrite, I am not even convinced that the StackLayout is necessary.